# Sylius - Taxon not Showing Products Assigned to it

Tags: sylius

I'm having some trouble getting products to show under the taxon they are assigned to.

I've assigned multiple products to a top-level taxon. I've double-checked to make sure that this setting saved, and they're definitely associated.

If I click on the "Browse Products" button on the taxon grid, I see a message saying that no products were found.

If I visit that taxon's front-end page: /t/taxon-name I also see the same error: There are no products to display.

In the code, I've checked the taxon object's getProducts() function, and it seems to return an empty collection:

```
ProductController.php on line 75:
Taxon {#4409 ▼
  #file: null
  #path: null
  #products: PersistentCollection {#4370 ▼
    -snapshot: []
    -owner: Taxon {#4409}
    -association: array:15 [ …15]
    -em: EntityManager {#2849 …10}
    -backRefFieldName: "taxons"
    -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#4479 …}
    -isDirty: false
    -initialized: false
    -coll: ArrayCollection {#4371 ▼
      -elements: [] <----------------------------- this here
    }
  }
  #id: 13
  #code: "test"
  #root: Taxon {#4369 ▶}
  #parent: Taxon {#4369 ▶ …2}
  #children: PersistentCollection {#4372 ▶}
  #left: 2
  #right: 3
  #level: 1
  #translations: PersistentCollection {#4375 ▶}
  #currentLocale: "en_US"
  #currentTranslation: TaxonTranslation {#4377 ▶}
  #fallbackLocale: "en_US"
  #createdAt: null
  #updatedAt: null
}
```

in the DB in *sylius_product* I see that multiple products show my taxon id under 'main_taxon_id'. I don't, however, see the products listed in *sylius_product_taxon*. Is this a problem? Perhaps it is because I'm using main taxons (top-level), rather than lower level taxons? If so, I need to be able to use only one level of taxon, so I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: Did you found any fixes for the same?